# Как вычленить номера телефонов в excel

Tags: регулярные-выражения, excel

Добрый вечер. Имеется столбец таблицы excel, в ячейках которого лежит куча слов, среди которых лежит номер телефона в формате: +7 (xxx) xxx xx xx. Телефон может быть в любом месте ячейки.
Как удалить из ячейки все, кроме этого телефона?

Comment: В гуглодоках - регуляркой, в экселе лучше макросов пока не придумывается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Maxim Yenaleyv: ...автозаменой. Можно заменить *+7 ( на +7

Еще проще, без доп. столбца с формулой.

1. Левую часть отсекаем, как и написано, автозаменой.
2. Выделяем диапазон, вкладка *Данные-Текст_по_столбцам-Фиксированной_ширины-Далее*-(задать ширину 18 символов)-*Далее*-(указать, с какой ячейки начать вставку)-*Готово*. Правая часть перенесена в отдельный столбец, его можно удалить.

'----------------------------

Чтобы не искажать исходные данные, для поиска создать шаблон, применяя подстановочные знаки: знак вопроса(?) - один любой символ, или звездочку (*) - любые символы в количестве >=0

```
=ПСТР(A1;ПОИСК("+7 (???) ??? ?? ??";A1);18)
```

Шаблон можно сократить, если есть уверенность в том, что сокращенный не будет подходить к другим фрагментам текста. Вполне может оказаться достаточным *"+7 (???)"*.

Шаблон можно оперативно менять, если записать его в в отдельную ячейку, в формуле поставить ссылку.

Если обрабатывается диапазон ячеек, в текстах которых номер телефона может отсутствовать:

```
=ЕСЛИОШИБКА(ПСТР(A1;ПОИСК("+7 (???)";A1);18);"")
```

Для *Excel-2003*:

```
=ЕСЛИ(ЕЧИСЛО(ПОИСК("+7 (???)";A1));ПСТР(A1;ПОИСК("+7 (???)";A1);18);"")
```

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой и быстрый способ - удалить автозаменой. Можно заменить *+7 ( на +7 ( это уберет все перед номером телефона, потом использовать функцию ЛЕВСИМВ(A1;18). A1 - ваша ячейка, 18 количество символов в номере (с пробелами)